# Is there any security risk with adding a **root's** public key to the local user's authorized_keys (so root to login as a user non-interactively?)

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualization, ubuntu

### Background:

I want to try unprivileged lxc containers a try on my small web server (hosting 2-4 users). Since the server is shared among friends, we decided to separate our services from the machine using lightweight containers. We envision that each user will run a host of unprivileged containers for each service of his with an option, that selected services/lxc containers will be started upon system start.

Under normal circumstances, one would simply use `setuid` and `setgid` stanza to run lxc containers in context of each user. Unfortunately it doesn't work; I suspect it has something to do with the `subuid` requirements of the unprivileged containers. Commands such as `sudo -u <user> -- lxc-autostart` or `su -l <user> -c lxc-autostart` may not change the `subuid` properties of the calling entity (which is root in case of upstart).

[So far, the only way of calling unprivileged containers from another account I found is by means of `ssh <user>@localhost lxc-autostart`](https://serverfault.com/questions/658101/what-is-the-best-practise-to-autostart-unprivileged-lxc-containers-on-ubuntu-14).

### The question rephrased

I can put such invocation on upstart script, but for it to work **I need to generate public certificate for root, and ensure that `<user>` will accept automatic logging from upstarts' `root`**. Is it secure?

The host is 64bit Ubuntu 14.04; it already uses ssh. As for Ubuntu's best practices, there is no password for root and root has empty `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

No `<user>` with automatic lxc containers uses `ecryptfs` (A.K.A. encrypted home), since it would be useless anyway on such setup.

Comment: I do not see any security risk in it, since it is almost the same as the `su - <user> -c` (you would need to compromise `root`'s account to make use of the key as its permissions are `0400`). But if you want an extra security, on the `authorized_keys` file add `from="127.0.0.1"` at the end of root's public key to avoid it being used from outside your box.

Comment: Wouldn't _cron_ be a much simpler solution? A script in the intended user's crontab to check if the service is running that starts the job if it is not live.

Comment: @DarkLighting No. This is a remote server, and the user usually will not be logged in interactively. (Actually we will use Puppet for the configuration, so in fact the user might *never* log in interactively)

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski crontab does not need a user to be logged in. Actually, what it does is just the opposite. [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) was created to automate system maintenance and administration jobs and, from what i could understand, what you want it to do is an administrative job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for the following reason: root could patch sshd to always try root's authorized_keys file as well as its own.

Of course if root's private key gets stolen you have a bad day. Don't allow that. You would be much happier if root's private key only exists in /root on the server.

If someone can become root they can steal it but that's of no account because they can do far worse. For example, patch sshd to take a hardcoded authorized key for any account.